# scrapy doesn't use a proxy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have socks5 proxy -> socks5://login:password@ip:port

i am tried:

```
class ProxyMiddleware:
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    # Set the location of the proxy
    request.meta['proxy'] = "http://ip:port"

    proxy_user_pass = "login:password"
    encoded_user_pass = base64.encodestring(proxy_user_pass)
    request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encoded_user_pass
```

middleware:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   'bog_name.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 100,
}
```

Scrapy doesn't use proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that scrapy doesn't support socks5 proxy out of the box. Here is [issue on Github](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/747) about it. And couple workarounds proposed by users in that topic - [one](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/747#issuecomment-1186730617), [two](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/747#issuecomment-308006521)